# String to HTML without extra surrounding div

Tags: javascript

I have a string representing `<a>` element, named `lal_output`. It has href, id and class. I want to convert this string to HTML:

```
lal_html = document.createElement('div');
lal_html.innerHTML = lal_output;
```

The problem is that it receives `<div>` wrapper. How can I get rid of it? I must use JavaScript without libraries.

Comment: That is exactly what `DocumentFragment` is for.

Comment: You haven't indicated how you're adding the element to the DOM. Assuming you're using `document.body.appendChild(lal_html)`, you could just use `document.body.appendChild(lal_html.firstChild)` to achieve what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DOMParser()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) as shown below

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var domString = '<a class="test" href="https://google.com">Google</a>';
var html = parser.parseFromString(domString, 'text/html');    
document.body.append(html.body.firstChild); //append to somewhere appropriate
```

A simple [POC](https://jsfiddle.net/jwLn06dh/)

Comment: Great stuff, I can store exact HTML in variable by adding one line after parsing: `parser = new DOMParser(); lal_html = parser.parseFromString(lal_output, 'text/html'); lal_html = lal_html.body.firstChild;`

Answer (score 1):

Although you could capture the child elements with a regex, a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) might be easier for your use case.

```
lal_html = document.createDocumentFragment();
lal_html.innerHTML = lal_output;

// Attach it to the node it belongs to in the DOM
element.appendChild(lal_html);
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't simply use `document.createDocumentFragment()` instead of `document.createElement('div')`. It generated no output on page. However, I found that this solution solves the problem. I wonder whether this or shorter way provided by Tico is better.

```
function stringToHTML(htmlStr) {    

    frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;

    while(temp.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    }

    return  frag;
}

lal_html = stringToHTML(lal_output);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using `insertAdjacentElement`

```
document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', lal_output);
```

Or if it needs to be placed after a specific element:

```
document.querySelector('someSpecificSelector').insertAdjacentElement('afterend', lal_output);
```

Other valid values for the first parameter are `'beforebegin'` and `'afterbegin'`. See [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)